# CURL Post values not working

Tags: php, post, curl

Using the script underneath, i'm trying to login to a webpage and afterwards perform a post that normally would have been triggerd by an Ajax script behind a button. The login works fine, but I can't simulate the Ajax action. Thanks for your assistance

```
<?php  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);     
$submit_url = "LOGINURL"; 

$submit_url2 = "OVERVIEWURL";   
$postdata = array('action.id' => urlencode('al_regid_162'), 
                    'action.component.id' => urlencode('form_aanvraag_filter'), 
                    'action.section.id' => urlencode('section1')); 

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url); 
$data = curl_exec($curl); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url2); 
$data = curl_exec($curl);

print($data);



curl_close($curl);    
?>
```

Comment: What type of error do you have?

Comment: Hello Oyeme, I don't get an error. I don't receive the data I expected as I think the Ajax button press simulation is incorrect.

Comment: Well,you can't simulate ajax click with curl.With "httplifeheader" you can see params and wich method are used for ajax.(POST OR GET).

Comment: Yes, i have searched for this and found the following: https://WEBPAGE/pimplus/service/aanvraagoverzicht?action.id=al_regid_162&action.component.id=form_aanvraag_filter&action.section.id=section1&field.aanvraag.filter.status=open&field.aanvraag.filter.filter=divisie&field.aanvraag.filter.extrafilter&field.aanvraag.filter.sortering=AANVRAAGID&field.aanvraag.filter.sortering.volgorde.checkbox=checkboxworkaround&field.aanvraag.filter.sortering.volgorde=true&field.aanvraag.zoeken

Comment: Is it a GET method? You can use  file_get_contents('your_url/WEBPAGE/pimplus/service'); CURL is only working for POST and PUT methods.

Comment: How would you add this in the script? I want to try but due to the login i'm not sure where to add the get_contents

Answer (score 1):

1. 1.Set up CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true in curl script.
2. Use `file_get_contents('your_url/WEBPAGE/pimplus/service');` after curl code.(For GET method only)

Comment: if(!file_get_contents('http://WEBPAGE/pimplus/service/aanvraagoverzicht?action.id=al_regid_162&action.component.id=form_aanvraag_filter&action.section.id=section1&field.aanvraag.filter.status=open&field.aanvraag.filter.sortering=AANVRAAGID')) { echo "Error"; } Putting this behind the CURL code results in an error.

Comment: Try to put this url to browser bar.I think your params are not valid.

Comment: Is it work? file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');               //full url to google

Comment: The error for the original links is the following failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized              requesting google results in the following:      failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: $context = stream_context_create(array( 'http' => array( 'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"). "\r\n". "Cookie: action.id=al_regid_162; action.component.id=form_aanvraag_filter; action.section.id=section1; field.aanvraag.filter.status=open; field.aanvraag.filter.sortering=AANVRAAGID\r\n" ) )); $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); echo $data; This code brings me as far as the Curl one, exact same result. Any thoughts how send the values?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$submit_url2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($postdata));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Sudhir, unfortunately this does not fix the issue. Any other thoughts?